# SSRS multiple iif statements rounds instead of keeping 2 decimal calculation

Tags: reporting-services

I have the following statement in a calculated field that will only return whole numbers instead of a 2 decimal dollar amount. If I only use one of the 3 iif conditions it works fine but as soon as I add the second or all 3 it will not return a decimal value. Ive also tried all 3 iif conditions separaately and they all work. It appears to be just the OR's causing the issue???

```
=
(iif ((Fields!loc.Value = "C08") OR (Fields!loc.Value = "C09"), Fields!price1.Value, Fields!price1.Value - Fields!price2.Value) )
```

OR

```
(iif ((Fields!loc.Value = "C33") OR (Fields!loc.Value = "C32") OR (Fields!loc.Value = "C10") OR (Fields!loc.Value = "C30"), 0, Fields!price1.Value - Fields!price2.Value) )
```

OR

```
(iif (Fields!price1.Value = 0, 0, Fields!price1.Value - Fields!price2.Value))
```

---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't write and `IIF` like that, you would need to nest you `IIF`s which would get a bit messy.

You might find it easier to use a `SWITCH` statement which is a bit easier to read.

I might not have understood your logic properly but it should be close enough. Note that the first expression that returns `true` is what will get returned so in thsi case I have assume that if `price1` is `0` then the returned value will always be zero, if this is incorrect, just re-order the expression pairs

```
=SWITCH(
  Fields!price1.Value = 0, 0,
  Fields!loc.Value = "C08" OR Fields!loc.Value = "C09", Fields!price1.Value,
  Fields!loc.Value = "C33" OR Fields!loc.Value = "C32" OR Fields!loc.Value = "C10" OR Fields!loc.Value = "C30", 0,
  True, Fields!price1.Value - Fields!price2.Value
)
```

This reads... "If price1 is zero then return 0" else "if loc is C08 or C09 return price1" else "if loc is C33, C32, C10 or C30 then return 0". Finally, if no previous test return `true`, then return price1-price2 .

The final `True` acts like and `else`

This could be simplified but I wanted to leave it as close to your original attempt as I could.

Comment: Thank you. That seems to have done the trick!!